# What is the difference between Keys.UP and Keys.ARROW_UP in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I just want to know how Keys.UP is different from Keys.ARROW_UP in selenium webdriver. I checked with both keys and they seem to have the same behavior and functionality, so I'm wondering:

1. If both represent the same functionality and behavior, then why two different representations?
2. If they are different, then in what cases will they work differently?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't `Keys.UP` fired upon a key-up event of **any** key?

Comment: Maybe one of them refers to 'numeric keypad up', and the other refers to the 'non numeric keypad up', as in Java [KeyEvent class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys.ARROW_UP and Keys.UP refer the same key code. There is no difference. So are Keys.ARROW_DOWN and Keys.DOWN. I guess it for convenience.

Looking into the source of [org.openqa.selenium.Keys](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.java) makes it clear

Looking further down the versions, the [earliest version (selenium-2.0-beta-2)](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.java?name=selenium-2.0-beta-2) has the developer comment clearly indicating that they are aliases. ARROW_LEFT, ARROW_RIGHT, ARROW_UP and ARROW_DOWN are aliases for LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN respectively.

Comment: One of the classic examples of "Use the source Luke!"

Comment: Ya that's my question if both key code are same then why two different representation. convenience could be one scenario but there would be some technical answer also.

Comment: Sorry to dissappoint you. There is no technical reason. Since the day of inception, the first version, the author had clearly added comment //alias against the code. ARROW_LEFT, ARROW_RIGHT, ARROW_UP and ARROW_DOWN are aliases for LEFT, RIGHT, UP and DOWN respectively. https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.java?name=selenium-2.0-beta-2

Answer (score 2):

Implementation says both are the same. ARROW_UP calls Keys.UP[image]